# Is there any difference between the "general form" and "standard form" of a line?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

> Is there any difference between the "general form" and "standard form" of a line?

I was thinking that there is no difference until I saw this exercise

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Well "intersept" and "standart form" does not help the credibility of the exercise's author! I have no idea what is considered the standard form or for that matter the general form. People use many forms (for lines in the plane). In linear spaces there is more uniformity.

Comment: It seems "standard form" is a definition from your book or from your course.  You must use that.  We do not know what it is.

Comment: @GEdgar maybe it has written there by mistake because there is a sentence in the lecture like this: _general (or standard ) form_

Comment: We could guess.  Maybe $y=mx+b$ is the "standard form".  But, really, that's just a guess.  Somewhere in your notes or in your reference, there will be a definition, or examples, of what is intended by that phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you a bit;

There are 7 well known forms of Straight Lines:

*General Form* : $ax + by + c = 0$
Significance: Any vector in the direction $ai + bj$ is perpendicular to this line.

*Slope Intercept Form* : $y = (\text{slope})x + (\text{$y$-intercept})$
Significance: As the name suggests, one can write a line in this form to directly compare to get slope and the y-intercept.

*One Point Slope form* : $(y-y_1) = (\text{slope})(x-x_1)$ where $(x_1,y_1)$ is a point on the line

*Two Point form* : Just replace slope from above equation with $(\text{slope}) = (y_2-y_1)/(x_2 - x_1)$ where $(x_1,y_1) (x_2,y_2)$ are two points on the line.

*Intercept form* : $x/a + y/b = 1$ 
Significance: Here $a$ and $b$ represent algebraic length of $x$ and $y$ intercept of the line on the respective axis.

*Normal Form*: (This one is not much used for day to day purposes but its better to know something than not): Let length of normal from origin be $p$ making angle $\theta$ with the $x$-axis. 
Now put $p/\cos(\theta) = a$ and $p/\sin(\theta) = b$ in above intercept form.

*Parametric Form*: (Most powerful form of straight line) Put $x = h + r\cos(\theta)$ and $y =k + r \sin(\theta)$ where $r$ is a variable representing distance from a point $(h,k)$ on the line and $tan(\theta)$ is the slope of the line.

Comment: thank you a lot

Comment: Your welcome (+1) :)

Comment: But the important message to take away is that few people are familiar with all these fine distinctions, and probably even fewer think them useful. If you want to talk about a particular form for the equation of a line it is best to be clear.

Comment: Indeed @almagest, Last two, despite being most powerful and useful, they are not taught in many high-schools.

Comment: Shouldn't the two point form be dependent on $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @Victor Glombik, It is indeed having two variables x and y. We just have to replace the slope from **One point Slope Form** to (y_2 - y_1)÷(x_2 - x_1)

Comment: Many classes at the college algebra level also define *standard form*, which is $Ax + By = C$.